How to run a github action workflow after release triggered workflow?
I have two separate workflows. One for testing and one for deploying. The deploy workflow should only run if the test workflow completes succesfully
Test workflow
name: run-tests
on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  ....do stuff

Deploy workflow
name: deploy
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["run-tests"]
    branches: [main]
    types:
      - completed
jobs:
  deploy:
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}

According to Github Actions docs and several Stack Overflow questions that is how it should be done. However, that doesn't work. The problem is that when I create a new release on Github, it triggers the first test workflow, but the name of the workflow is the name of the release tag .i.e v1.2.3!
The workflows will run correctly if I set a manual trigger on the test workflow and run it manually. Then the workflow will get the name run-tests and the trigger for the deploy works.
How can I make the delpoy workflow trigger to work also when the test workflow is triggered by a new release?

Is that double on: a typo in the deploy workflow? The workflow name should remain the same, however, the run-name may change. An MCVE as a public repo would be helpful to understand and debug this issue.

Is this article already helping you?

@azeem it's a typo. I will edit the question and fix it.

Also I will take a look at that article linked by @flaxel. Thank you both!

Wouldn't it work as you expect by removing the branches: [main] criteria from the deploy workflow?
